# Cannot change date format with VBA in some Excel versions

Tags: excel, vba

In some versions of Excel, I have half of the dates in the format Mar/31/2018 and the cell formatting is general and the other half are Date format and 03/31/2018. These are exported from somewhere so I cannot change that. These dates are used in a pivot table.

I have tried

```
Range("C2:C200").NumberFormat = "m/dd/yyyy"
```

to override the format and match them all to the same format, but in the pivot table it always shows Mar/31/2018 instead of 03/31/2018 for the top half. And the Mar/31/2018 date is left aligned while the other half is right aligned with the correct format 03/31/2018.

```
Range("C2:C200").Value.NumberFormat = "m/dd/yyyy" does not work either. 

For i = 2 to lastRow Step 1
dateString = Cells(i, 3).Value
Cells(i, 3).Value = DateValue(dateString) only works for the cells that are already in custom or date format and not for the general format cells.
```

I'd like to be able to override the general format to a proper date format.

Comment: Try using `CDate`.  It will convert a string to a date.  When data is exported from another app or website, it often comes in as a text string.  Another option is to copy, paste multiply by 1.

Comment: Will give that a try. Will CDate throw an error on the cells that are already correct?

Comment: `cdate` does not throw an errow on a date input.    

`debug.print format(cdate(dateserial(2018,6,3)),"YYYY-MM-DD")`  
 => 2018-06-03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Convert2Date()
    Dim iCt As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim dateStr As Variant
    Dim dateArr() As String
    Dim YearInt As Integer, MonInt As Integer, dayInt As Integer
    'Range("C2:C200").Value.NumberFormat = "m/dd/yyyy" 'does not work either.
    'For i = 2 To lastRow
        'dateString = Cells(i, 3).Value
        'Cells(i, 3).Value = DateValue(dateString) 'only works for the cells that are already in custom or date format and not for the general format cells.


    lastRow = Range("C1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    For iCt = 2 To lastRow
        dateStr = Cells(iCt, 3).Value
        If Not (dateStr = "") Then
            If IsDate(dateStr) Then
                Cells(iCt, 5) = "isdate = OK!"
                Cells(iCt, 4) = CDate(dateStr)
            Else
                'Cells(iCt, 4) = CDate(dateStr)
                dateArr = Split(dateStr, "/")
                MonInt = ConvertMonth(dateArr(0))
                dayInt = CInt(dateArr(1))
                YearInt = CInt(dateArr(2))
                Cells(iCt, 4).Value = DateSerial(YearInt, MonInt, dayInt)
                Cells(iCt, 5) = "CONVERTED"
                Cells(iCt, 5).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        End If
    Next iCt
End Sub

Function ConvertMonth(MonthStr As String) As Integer
    Dim tempStr As String
    Dim tempInt As Integer
    tempStr = LCase(MonthStr)
    Select Case tempStr
        Case "jan"
            tempInt = 1
        Case "feb"
            tempInt = 2
        Case "mar"
            tempInt = 3
        Case "apr"
            tempInt = 4
        Case "may"
            tempInt = 5
        Case "jun"
            tempInt = 6
        Case "jul"
            tempInt = 7
        Case "aug"
            tempInt = 8
        Case "sep"
            tempInt = 9
        Case "oct"
            tempInt = 10
        Case "nov"
            tempInt = 11
        Case "dec"
            tempInt = 12
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "undefined month string"
            tempInt = 0
    End Select
    ConvertMonth = tempInt '(added, corrected in June 2022)
End Function
```

Comment: In the function `ConvertMonth` the line  `ConvertMonth = tempInt` as a last line was missing! As a result the above `Mar/31/2018` converted to `31.12.2017`  instead of the correct `31.03.2018`. (see pic)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that some of your "dates" are actually *Text* values.  To convert them to a common "real" format.  Select the cells and run this:

```
Sub DateUnifier()
    Dim r As Range, d As Date, s As String, nf As String, arry
    nf = "m/d/yyyy"
    For Each r In Selection
        s = r.Text
        If s <> "" Then
            arry = Split(s, "/")
            If UBound(arry) = 2 Then
                If IsNumeric(arry(0)) Then
                    r.Clear
                    r.Value = DateValue(s)
                    r.NumberFormat = nf
                Else
                    r.Clear
                    r.Value = DateSerial(CInt(arry(2)), konvert(arry(0)), CInt(arry(1)))
                    r.NumberFormat = nf
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

Public Function konvert(st As Variant) As Integer
    mnths = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
    i = 1
    For Each mn In mnths
        If st = a Then
            konvert = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next mn
End Function
```

**CORRECTION:**

There are errors in the *konvert()* function, use this instead:

```
Public Function konvert(st As Variant) As Integer

    mnths = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
    i = 1
    For Each mn In mnths
        If st = mn Then
            konvert = i
            Exit Function
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next mn
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, seems they are just a string with general cell format. I can run this on all cells (even those that are already correct) right?

Comment: @MJ95 Yes............... **just be sure the month abbreviations in the code match the abbreviations in your data!**

Comment: Makes sense, will try it out. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to use LCase in your **nice** konvert function! ;-)

Comment: @simple-solution  Good idea, might want to use *Proper()* or some other alternative

Comment: I'm in Europe and I do get wrong date conversion from your code? example 1: Apr/01/2018 => 01.12.2017 example 2: Mar/31/2018 => 31.12.2017 ???

Comment: @simple-solution  I found some problems and posted a **correction**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent and simple-solution Hmm, not sure which answer to use! I think both work :) Thanks

Comment: @MJ95 I would mark **simple-solution's** response as the ***Answer***, it is better than mine.